# Is 'Semprini' an HHGG expletive?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

I seem to remember 'Semprini' being an obscenity used by Zaphod.  Did I imagine it?  I have discovered it was used as such by Monty Python, as was 'Belgium'.

Comment: Which version would you have heard/read this in?

Comment: I found a Google Books result from a history of DA and HHGG that mentioned "Semprini" and implied it might have come from the original radio play, but it's too tenuous for a full answer.

Comment: There was a late evening radio program (music) on BBC radio called 'Semprini's Serenade'. Not my kind of music but it's bland, easy listening, style may have been a target here. As an aside, I met Semprini himself many years ago when he was looking at my dad's boat with a possibility of buying it.

Comment: Belgium was not used as an obscenity. The English and American printings differed. The award, in the English printing, was for most gratuitous use of the word f***.

Answer (score 5):

I have heard the first and second HHGG radio series ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(radio_series) ), seen the TV series ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(TV_series) ), and read the books ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy ). I do not remember the word "Semprini" being used in any of them.

Google found me the fragment "tried and tested Semprini-like ultimate obscenity of 'Belgium'", in a Google Books copy of *The Frood: The Authorised and Very Official History of Douglas Adams and the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* by Jem Roberts ( https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Frood/nqeGCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=douglas+adams+semprini&pg=PA212&printsec=frontcover ). Google Books won't let me see the previous page, which contains the start of that phrase. However, from the wording, I suspect it is indeed referring to a Monty Python episode in which "Semprini" is used as an expletive.

This episode can be seen on YouTube:

The video's owner has titled it "Monty Python Semprini Sketch". The word first appears shortly after 0:47 on the video, where a presenter is apologising for bad language in the previous sketch and pointing to a list of rude words which are "not to be used again on this programme". They are "B✼M", "B✼TTY", "P✼X", "KN✼CKERS", "KN✼CKERS", "W✼✼-W✼✼", and "SEMPRINI".

Immediately after that, a new sequence starts in which a pharmacist shouts to his customers, "Right! Who's got a boil on his Semprini, then?" and is hustled out by a policeman. The screenshots below show the word "SEMPRINI" being shown, and the pharmacist with policeman:
[image: Presenter showing the word "SEMPRINI"]
[image: Pharmacist, with policeman entering stage left]
[image: Policeman hustling pharmacist out stage right]

PEW is right to say in the comment that *Semprini's Serenade* was a BBC-radio music programme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberto_Semprini . That Wikipedia link also describes the Monty Python episode.

So to summarise, I don't believe Zaphod ever used the word "Semprini". But the biographer Jem Roberts appears to have done so: as an analogy, based on that Monty Python episode, to explain how Zaphod uses "Belgium".

It's amusing that the Monty Python Dictionary at http://www.cardinalfang.net/misc/dictionary.html#S defines "Semprini" thus:

> Semprini: 1. Possibly a rude word (in Monty Python land)

> 2.There’s some debate about the real meaning. The general consensus though   is that its a type of aftershave.

I wonder where they got the aftershave idea from. Moral: never trust anything you read on the Internet.

**Update**

I found a Portuguese translation of *The Frood*. This is *Douglas Adams. A Espetacular e Incrível Vida de Douglas Adams e do Guia do Mochileiro das Galáxias*. The text doesn't break at exactly the same place, so despite Google Books again not letting me see the previous page, I was able to find out more of what Jem Roberts was saying. Here's my translation back into English:

> … The episode where Arthur Dent’s house is demolished in the first
> book had originally been embellished with several "fucks". However, it
> would be more difficult to clean up the offending word in the Rory
> award for the "most gratuitous use of the word ‘fuck’ in a serious
> screenplay", because that was essential to the joke. It was only in
> the United States, where the Cosmic Cutiepie had attracted a much
> greater child audience, that the editors insisted on finding
> alternatives. They replaced the F-word with the tried-and-tested
> Semprini-like obscenity of "Belgium", complete with explanation lifted
> from the radio."

I'm guessing at the first few words in the first sentence, as Google Books had hidden that part of the Portuguese text. (The visible part begins "demolição de sua casa".) But it must have been something close to what I wrote. For clarity, I've also removed a mention of Wowbagger. The Portuguese says that something similar happened to something he said. Finally, part of the last sentence is from the English original. I presume that "explanation lifted from the radio" refers to the announcer's explanatory voiceovers.

See also the entry for "Belgium", from https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Belgium ( https://web.archive.org/web/20201210214840/https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Belgium ). It says:

> In the US version of the third novel, Life, the Universe and
> Everything, the word is used to replace the word "fuck" which was in
> the British publication, when referring to the Rory Award for "The
> Most Gratuitous Use of the Word 'Fuck/Belgium' in a Serious
> Screenplay." Arthur Dent nearly gets punched for asking the girl
> explaining the award, "have you ever been to Belgium in fact?"